# How to switch language in windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

[image]

What is the best way to select desired language resources `if` or `switch` ?

For example I have these languages: english, french.

Currently available languages gives them as a list and added them to a panel stack.

I want to do that in Windows Phone 8.0.

Comment: switch must be a better way to do so

Comment: You'll have to explain a bit more. If and switch are the same thing to a compiler basically, but don't understand how it relates to a panel stack etc

Comment: stackpanel is like an list with many items, when select one language, need to change some text, description

Comment: Usually for mobile apps you just let the OS handle that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a multi language app you can use Localized Resource Files

[Here's a tutorial that you can follow](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/localizing-a-windows-phone-8-application--cms-22989)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `dictionary` with key value, so that if you add a language after your code doesn't change.